# Creating HTML elements in JS (without jQuery)? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js

I'm new to node.js. Here is my code:
[My Code](http://jsfiddle.net/653g7rac/)

More specifically, here is what I have for JS:

```
let torontoTeams = [
    {"name": "Raptors", "description": "The Raptors compete in the National Basketball Association (NBA), as a member club of the league's Eastern Conference Atlantic Division."},

    {"name": "Maple Leafs", "description": "The Maple Leafs are one of the 'Original Six' NHL teams, and have won the Stanley Cup 13 times."},

    {"name": "Blue Jays", "description": "The Blue Jays compete in Major League Baseball (MLB) as a member club of the American League (AL) East division."}
];
for (let i=0; i < torontoTeams.length; i++) {

    let newSection = document.createElement('section');
    document.appendChild(newSection);

    let newTeam = document.createElement('h1');
    newTeam.appendChild(document.createTextNode(torontoTeams[i].name));

    let newDesc = document.createElement('P');
    newDesc.appendChild(document.createTextNode(torontoTeams[i].description));

    document.createElement(newSection);
    newSection.appendChild(newTeam);
    newSection.appendChild(newDesc);
};
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with creating the HTML elements.

Comment: This is wrong: `document.createElement(newSection);`  `.createElement()` takes a tagName as the argument, not a DOM element and you want to put the section into `document.body`, not `document`.

Comment: *"I'm new to node.js"* - Node.js runs JavaScript on the server, where it doesn't make sense to be creating DOM elements. Is the code shown supposed to run in the browser rather than in Node.js?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to run in the browser, but I guess node.js isn't required at all in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append only one element to `document`. Append the `section`s to `document.body` or create a container and target it with `document.querySelector`

```js
var body = document.body,
    torontoTeams = [
    {"name": "Raptors", "description": "The Raptors compete in the National Basketball Association (NBA), as a member club of the league's Eastern Conference Atlantic Division."},

    {"name": "Maple Leafs", "description": "The Maple Leafs are one of the 'Original Six' NHL teams, and have won the Stanley Cup 13 times."},

    {"name": "Blue Jays", "description": "The Blue Jays compete in Major League Baseball (MLB) as a member club of the American League (AL) East division."}
];


for (let i=0; i < torontoTeams.length; i++) {

    var newSection = document.createElement('section');
    body.appendChild(newSection); // append to body.

    var newTeam = document.createElement('h1');
    newTeam.appendChild(document.createTextNode(torontoTeams[i].name));

    var newDesc = document.createElement('P');
    newDesc.appendChild(document.createTextNode(torontoTeams[i].description));

    // document.createElement(newSection); What is this suppose to do? It doesn't work.
    
    newSection.appendChild(newTeam);
    newSection.appendChild(newDesc);
    
};
```

```css
section {
  display: block;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 33vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there something that I should change for it to work in browser? The code works when I run it on here and on jsfiddle, but not in-browser when I make the same changes in my js file.

Comment: @daezilla, replace `let` with `var` because most browsers don't support `let` keyword (from ES6) yet.

Comment: var would be my go-to keyword, however, the instructions in this exercise asks to use `let` instead.

Comment: @daezilla, assuming the browser supports `let`, you should be fine. Present the work you've done using Google Chrome.